# Adding anonymous property to an object using Symbol() function

Tags: javascript, object, symbols

I am trying to create an anonymous property on an object using the Symbol() function.

[image]

When I tried to get the "property descriptor" for the anonymous property, it's *enumerable* flag was set to **true**.

[image]

However, the **for..in** loop failed to detect the anonymous property despite the fact that it was enumerable.

[image]

Also, the [Symbol - Glossary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Symbol) page of MDN says that -

> When a symbol value is used as the identifier in a property assignment, the property (like the symbol) is anonymous; and also is **non-enumerable**. Because the property is non-enumerable, it will not show up as a member in the loop construct "for( ... in ...)".

But in my case, the property turned out to be **enumerable**.

**UPDATE** - Working example :

```
function foo(a){
    var prop = Symbol();
    this[prop] = a;
}

var obj = new foo(96);

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj));

for(var x in obj){
    console.log("Object property - " + obj[x]);
}
```

Comment: Please attach a working snippet instead of images.

Comment: @gurvinder372 https://jsfiddle.net/f24x8o4r/2/

Comment: in my case for in loop output is empty. prop is enumerable.

Comment: Exactly. But according to MDN, the property should be **non-enumerable** and so, the for..in output should be empty.

Comment: This is what MDN says for for..in loop "Enumerable properties show up in for...in loops unless the property's name is a Symbol." @AnimeshKumar

Comment: @VivekN Thanks!! But I don't understand why is the "Symbol" property enumerable? Shouldn't it be non-enumerable?

Comment: @AnimeshKumar I am taking a guess here that the reason could be since they are properties of an object and when you do Object.assign only enumerable properties get copied.
Also the reason for..in does not work with Symbols is that [[Enumerable]] only works with string as keys.